# Using Zepto with prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, zepto

I want to use Zepto in a page that has both jQuery and Prototype.
But i can't find `noConflict()` in Zepto documentation. I use my jquery code with prototype on the same page so no-conflict is very important.

Can someone let me know how to use Zepto in noConflict mode?

Comment: Hold on, why are you including jQuery *and* Zepto?

Comment: Zepto boasts that it is supposed to be a lighter and faster jQuery. Why are you trying to load a lightweight library on a page that already has two heavier libraries - one of which Zepto is based on?

Comment: why zepto? - Because Zepto has better animation performance.
why jQuery? - Because jQuery is cross-browser compatible.
Afaik Zepto doesn't support IE

Comment: It looks like [here in the source](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js#L642) if you include Zepto after jQuery or whatever library that *will* get `$`, it will not set it (defacto `noConflict()`.

Comment: @Jared Thanks.
Post this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [here in the source](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js#L642) if you include Zepto after jQuery or whatever library that *will* get `$`, it will not set it (defacto `noConflict()`):

```
// If `$` is not yet defined, point it to `Zepto`
window.Zepto = Zepto
'$' in window || (window.$ = Zepto)
```